Game - two players take turn moving a marker to an adjacent square in a 9x9 grid
A marker is placed in the centre of a $9$x$9$ grid. Ann and Beth take turns moving the marker to one of the adjacent squares (one sharing a side) provided that this square has never been occupied by a marker before. Ann goes first. The player unable to move loses. The question posited was: which of the players can guarantee a win?
Upon MJD's suggestion, the question is easily answered if we colour the grid like a checkerboard and place $2$x$1$ dominoes across the rest of the board such that each domino contains one white and one black square. Ann must move into one of these dominoes, and Beth will always move into the other square contained in the domino. So, for each move of Ann, Beth will always have a move, proving that Beth can always win this game.
Now, what if the grid was generally of size $n$ x $m$ and the marker could start at any position on the grid?
I was able to solve till the following:
Clearly, if either n or m are even, by similar logic with dominoes, Ann can always win the game. If both $n$ and $m$ are odd, but the distance of the starting position from all sides has the same parity, then by similar logic, Beth can always win (the original $9$x$9$ case with central starting position was actually a special case of this).
The problem arises when we consider the case where both $n$ and $m$ are odd, and the distance of the marker from one pair of sides has different parity than the other pair of sides. We can no longer divide the remaining squares into dominoes. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

LColor the squares like a checkerboard and cover it with dominoes.

Let the board have the corners colored black and be checkerboard colored. The marker starts on a white square.  Cover the board with dominos except one black square. Ann moves to the black square of the domino that the marker is on before her turn.  When all the dominos are used the marker is on a black square and the available square is also black, so no move is possible and Beth loses.

Ah, can't believe I missed that. Thanks for completing the solution!
